# Can Lezyne Stainless-12 chain tool handle be used as tire lever?

Tags: tire-lever

This really makes me curious, Lezyne Stainless-20 has a separate tool -- tire lever (however I don't see clearly on pictures how it looks like). The specification of Stainless-12 does not list tire level, but judging how the chain tool looks like it seems it could be used as tire level (unofficialy).

So maybe I rephrase my question to be more precise -- did anyone **successfully** (without breaking/bending the tool and cracking the rim, etc) use the handle of chain tool (of Stainless-12, lower brother) as tire lever?

**Once again:** I am asking about version -12, not -20!

Update: Just to avoid any misunderstanding -- Lezyne chain tool handle:

[image]

Image taken from http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/

Comment: That chain tool handle spins.  How do you think you could get enough leverage to use it as a tire lever?

Comment: In a word, no.  You should carry a separate set of tire levers or a Quick Stick if you expect to fix tires on the road.

Comment: @Blam, what do you mean "spins"? What is the minimum length of tire lever so one could get enough leverage?

Comment: If you're talking about that flap on the chain tool, that's there to hold the chain tool from turning as the main tool handle is turned to thread in the screw.  It is the wrong shape to use a tire lever, and it's positioned improperly.  If desperate I might try using it for that, but there would be considerable risk of damaging the tube or rim, plus it would be painfully slow (if it worked at all).

Comment: Here is the best picture I've found: http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/lezyne-stainless-12-multi-tool/rp-prod24671?gs=1&gclid=CjwKEAjwjKOpBRChjsTyicbFy3QSJADP1gTNrAlgBXNSEOnOugW0HQZViRnWqkfy_D16bBSVSvGLchoC1cXw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Spin - rotate.  It is the threads on chain tool.  That tab is like 1 inch long.  The minimum is longer than that.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, yes, this one. But see the updated post, because the key issue here is the handle itself. I am not afraid of the speed, in my case I am heading home when accident happens, my only concern is making some dent in the rim or damaging the handle.

Comment: @Blam, what do you need the threads for? I am talking about the handle itself -- just to grab into a hand. However true, it would be smart to put something rigid through the threads for lengthening the handle, and thus gaining the leverage. This is however another story. Here -- handle only :-).

Comment: What you need is a [Quick Stick](http://www.amazon.com/Quik-Stik-Bicycle-Tire-Changer/dp/B0055F0FK0).

Comment: Answer a question for us:  Why do you not want to carry a proper tire lever of some sort?

Comment: @DanielRHicks, I don't see how QuickStick is better than regular tire lever (I use Schwalbe ones), I can and I use the same move the guy in the video does, however it depends what kind of tire I have. The reason for the question is simple -- I am just curious. One tool less, the better, after all this is why multi-tools exists. And for the record, I already have 3 pairs of tire levers :-) so it is not about saving the money, just curiosity how far optimization can go. Btw. I already noticed you can drill a hole in that handle, like in Carbon version.

Comment: Believe me, the Quick Stick is better than a regular tire lever.  As to using that flangy thing on the Lezyne tool, I'd much rather use a plain screwdriver, or even a nail clipper.

Comment: Your multi-tool logic makes no sense.  Lenzyne has a multi-tool that it includes a tire lever.  If you want a multi-tool with a tire lever then why not just buy the tool with the tire level.  They make the tool - if chain break can be used for tires then why would they have a separate attachement for tires?

Answer (score 2):

Based on lezyne's site specs, that 12 tool is not meant to be used as a tire lever.

I would say, having had a lot of experience using make-shift tire-levers while on the job as a bike messenger, that it would damage your rim, and cause aggressive wear to the tire sidewall (leading to side-wall blowout).

Save yourself the $20-80 in tires, and the $100+ in a rim/wheel. Buy some Pedros from your nearest bike shop.
http://pedros.com/products/tools/wheel-and-tire/tire-levers/

http://www.lezyne.com/product-mtools-stainlesstools.php#.VSkorJFVhBd

12 style:
"TOOL BITS:
    Hex 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8mm      Star Shaped T25
    Phillips-Head       Chain Breaker: (9/10/11 speed)
    Spoke Wrenches: Mavic Mtv, 3.22, 3.45"

Note: They explicitly list the 20 as having a tire lever, which is clearly a different tool.

Comment: In my opinion, the Quick Stick is far better than standard tire levers.

Comment: I can't say I have any experience with them, though I've seen them around. I could see how the narrower leverage point creates less tension while trying to remove a tough tire. Maybe a quick stick and a pedros?
I prefer the pedros because I've never felt it come close to breaking, though I've broken a park-tools, and 2 other no-name levers. @DanielRHicks